# How to add a hover event handler in JQuery, that will just target sibling elements with the same parent element?

Tags: html, jquery, css

how to make hover over one div to trigger changes in another div, but not to affect to another div with Jquery. Here is [example](https://jsfiddle.net/daniel_juri/vx54s6rd/80/)

I know for this option but It's not working for me

```
    $(function() {
  $(".single-holder-image").hover(function() {
    $(".read-more-a-black", this).css('color', '#a2d0ba');
  }, function() {
    // on mouseout, reset the background colour
    $(".read-more-a-black", this).css('color', '');
  });
});
```

maybe I need to change html structure

```
<div class="big-holder">

  <div class="single-post-holder">
  <a class="" href="#">
    <div class="single-holder-image">
       <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/717/200/300.jpg?hmac=OJYQhMLNcYlN5qz8IR345SJ7t6A0vyHzT_RdMxO4dSc" alt="">
    </div>
  </a>
  <div class="description-holder">
    <p class="category name "></p>
    <a class="read-more-a-black" href="#"><h5>Title 2</h5></a>
    <a class="read-more-a-black-p" href="#">lorem test test test test</a>
    <div class="pdf-holder">
      <p>Tools:</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

  <div class="single-post-holder">
  <a class="" href="#">
    <div class="single-holder-image">
       <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/717/200/300.jpg?hmac=OJYQhMLNcYlN5qz8IR345SJ7t6A0vyHzT_RdMxO4dSc" alt="">
    </div>
  </a>
  <div class="description-holder">
    <p class="category name "></p>
    <a class="read-more-a-black" href="#"><h5>Title 2</h5></a>
    <a class="read-more-a-black-p" href="#">lorem test test test test</a>
    <div class="pdf-holder">
      <p>Tools:</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


</div>
```

Also, will  I be able to do the same when the mouse is hover over the title to trigger image and gets a transform: scale?

Comment: Something you might want to consider is altering the structure so that `single-post-holder` is the anchor tag instead of it only wrapping the image. At that point, on hover of `single-post-holder` you can change the color anything inside with purely CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$(this)` in the `.hover()` event handler callback.

This way just the very element where the event occured will be selected.

After that some [JQuery DOM traversing](https://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/) with `.parents()` and `.find()` and problem solved:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".single-holder-image").hover(function() {
    $(this).parents(".single-post-holder").find(".read-more-a-black").css('color', '#a2d0ba');
  }, function() {
    // on mouseout, reset the background colour
    $(this).parents(".single-post-holder").find(".read-more-a-black").css('color', '');
  });
});
```